# Crop images based on specific color

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am having trouble in detecting flaw pattern of steel.

I attached a picture below in which you can find a steel laying on the green ground. It's quite easy for people to identify the steel since the colors are different. I would like to crop the steel out of the green ground first, and I wonder how can I do so with `cv2`

I appreciate any advice and information.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this. This will give you a starting point https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-detect-an-object-from-static-image-and-crop-it-from-the-image-using-openCV

Comment: You can simply use color segmentation and contour detection to get it working

Answer (score 0):

With straight lines and such strong color contrast you should have success with the cv2.Canny() function.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html

Another idea would work if all of your images are roughly the same green/grey combo and mostly flat horizontally. You could throw out any row of the image that has too much green in the RGB values.